# my pop( ) function does not delete the top element of a list, but rather a random one

Tags: python, stack

I have created the following pop function:

```
def pop(arr):
    if not isempty(arr):
        topelement = arr[len(arr)-1]
        arr.remove(topelement)
        return topelement
```

And it worked correctly until I used it in order to reverse order of a stack of numbers and operators:

```
"3 6 2 + * 14 3 4 + + /"
```

into

```
"/ + + 4 3 14 * + 2 6 3".
```

In first iteration of while loop shown below it pushed "/" operator to the auxiliary stack and deleted it from the top of entry, which is OK - but in the second iteration it deleted "+" sign from the middle of the entry instead of the plus sign with the highest index.

```
def evaluation(eq):
    entryunsplit = errpostfix(eq)
    entry = entryunsplit.split()
    lengthofentry = len(entry)
    stack = [] 
    
    while len(stack) != lengthofentry:
        push(stack,pop(entry))
```

Could someone please explain me why didn't it delete the last element and how can I avoid that error?

I am putting the whole code below in case some other element turns out to be significant.

```
stack1 = []
max_size = 30

def push(arr,a):
    if len(arr) < max_size:
        arr.append(a)


def isempty(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def top(arr):
    if not isempty(arr):
        return arr[len(arr)-1]

def pop(arr):
    if not isempty(arr):
        topelement = arr[len(arr)-1]
        arr.remove(topelement)
        return topelement
       
def errpostfix(eq):
    entry = eq.split()
    opstack = []
    exit = []
    priorities = { "+": 1, "-": 1, "*": 0, "/": 0 }
    for token in entry:
        if token == "(":
            push(opstack,token)
        elif token == "*" or token == "/" or token == "+" or token == "-":
            if top(opstack) == "*" or top(opstack) == "/" or top(opstack) == "+" or top(opstack) == "-": 

                while not isempty(opstack) and priorities[top(opstack)] >= priorities[token]:
                    push(exit,pop(opstack))
                    isempty(opstack)
            push(opstack,token)
        elif token == ")":
            while top(opstack) != "(":
                push(exit,pop(opstack))
            pop(opstack)
        else:
            push(exit,token)
        
    while not isempty(opstack):
        push(exit, pop(opstack))

    output = " ".join(exit)
    return output



def isop(ch):
    if ch == "+" or ch == "-" or ch == "*" or ch == "/":
        return True
    else:
        return False

def evaluation(eq):
    entryunsplit = "3 6 2 + * 14 3 4 + + /"
    entry = entryunsplit.split()
    lengthofentry = len(entry)
    stack = []
    
    while len(stack) != lengthofentry:
        push(stack,pop(entry))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remove()` operation on a list will delete the *first* occurrence of an item in that list, is not "random" (check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)). If there are several repeated elements, the first one encountered will be the one that gets deleted. To delete the last element, simply use the built-in `pop()` method:

```
def pop(arr):
    if not isempty(arr):
        topelement = arr[-1]
        arr.pop()
        return topelement
```